# Implement Replay attacks in python

Tags: attacks, server, denial-of-service, python, ocsp

For an assignment I have to implement a proof of concept and (optionally attack it). The part of OCSP is working so far. I have a client that sends the request to a server, the server verifies if the certificate is valid. But I wanted to do a replay attack to it.
My idea was to first capture the traffic between the client and the server and capture a server response. Then, later I would flood the server with requests (or a SYN flood attack, I don't know which would work best) and, when the client requests the status of the same certificate, I would just replay the request I captured earlier.

However, I'm having some issues implementing this. I have the OCSP thing working (a server listening on port 8080 and captured traffic with wireshark), but when I try to put an attacker listening on the same port as the server, I get an error. How am I supposed to eavesdrop this connection so I can replay the response?

Comment: *"but when I try to put an attacker listening on the same port as the server, I get an error."* - this looks like a programming problem, which is off-topic here. Try at stackoverflow.com, but don't forget to add the details of what you are actually doing (minimal reproducible code) and the exact error you get.

Comment: As a troubleshooting question, it lacks any detail that could help with troubleshooting